# How to get hold of a method name without using magic strings

Tags: java

In java is there any library to get the field name without using any magic strings, for example, for following class

```
class User
{
int id;

int getId()
{
return id;
}

void setId(int id)
{
this.id = id;
}
}
```

Now what i want is something like this,

```
String fieldName = Utility.getFieldName(User.getId());
```

this should return text "id"

I know this is not achievable by usual means, but I am thinking if it can be done by wrapping the User class with a dynamic proxy (so this would be more like

```
String fieldName = Utility.getFieldName(Utility.createProxy<User>().getId());
```

) and intercepting the method call and obtaining method name from stack, and use some thread joins to look it like a simple method call when looked at the Utility class. Does anyone knows if there is any library to do this type of operation?

Answer (score 2):

This may be done using [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Comment: but it would use magic strings, which is the one I need to get rid of

Comment: Yeah, but when you call `User.getId()` you get an int as a return value, not the field.

Comment: yes, that is why I wanted to know if there is anyway to do it by creating a dynamic proxy to intercept the method and get hold of the method name using a call stack.